# Android notifyDataSetChanged() not working

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am working on ArrayAdapter and ListView. I have an Activity **A** and Activity **B**. Activity **A** starts an Activity **B** (`startActivityForResult()`) and when Activity **B** is finished, it returns the result back to Activity **A**.

Activity **A**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    listViewPrayerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_prayerlist);
    prayerList = new ArrayList<PrayerSetting>();
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(Utils.PRAYER_LIST)) {
        prayerList.clear();
        prayerList.addAll((ArrayList<PrayerSetting>) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra(Utils.PRAYER_LIST));
        pAdapter = new PrayerAdapter(this, R.layout.prayer_list_item,
                prayerList);
  }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null && data.hasExtra(Utils.SETTINGS)) {
        PrayerSetting p = (PrayerSetting) data
                .getSerializableExtra(Utils.SETTINGS);
        prayerList.set(itemClickedPosition, p);
        pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // UI/List doesn't change
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong! I have tried many solutions but still don't get it.

1. [Stackoverflow Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033481/android-notifydatasetchanged-not-working)
2. [Stackoverflow Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422120/notifydatasetchange-not-working-from-custom-adapter)
3. [Stackoverflow Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598621/notifydatasetchanged-not-working)
4. [Blogspot link](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html)
5. [Stackoverflow Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453511/simpleadapter-notifydatasetchanged)

I do understand that its a basic question. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how are you setting the adapter? please post

Comment: listView.setAdapter(pAdapter);

Comment: can you please post complete code i.e. adapter initializing and your custom adapter

Comment: Is it data really changed?

Comment: Try re-setting the adapter. I've had this issue before and this worked.

Comment: Yes data is changing, I have logged it and also checked it in debug mode.

Comment: @liarspocker Resetting mean, clearing all data and then setting list adapter again?

Comment: Just setting the adapter again

Comment: Still not working. I have tried all things but the result is same.

Answer (score -1):

Try moving

```
pAdapter = new PrayerAdapter(this, R.layout.prayer_list_item,
    prayerList);
```

before if statement in onCreate